# Selecting range of data in an array

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to select a range of data in a 2D array in VB.net in an if statement. Rather than doing something like:

```
If griddata(0, 0) and griddata(0, 1) and griddata (0, 2) = 0 Then
```

Would I be able to do something like:

```
If griddata(0, 0 to 0, 2) = 0 Then
```

Obviously the second code snippet is incorrect, but I'm asking if selecting a range in an array can be done in a similar way rather than defining every single part of the array I want manually, as I feel this would be if not inefficient, time consuming to write.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first line is missing two `= 0`. Otherwise, you'd do a *bitwise AND* and then compare it to `0`, which is probably not what you intended. Also, you can use `AndAlso`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility to get rid of the redundancy, but, honestly, it's not really easier to read:

```
If Enumerable.Range(0, 3).All(Function(i) griddata(0, i) = 0) Then
```

or

```
If {0, 1, 2}.All(Function(i) griddata(0, i) = 0) Then
```

References:

- [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Enumerable.All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That looks harder to understand at first glance and harder to remember. I think I'll stick with the old fashioned way for now unless another option arises since my data set is quite small. Thanks, anyway. I'll be sure to look back at this answer when I use a larger array.